# Gulp Karma "Script error"

Tags: gulp, karma-runner, karma-mocha, gulp-karma

I'm using gulp-karma + mocha + chai + sinon in order to unit test some front end.

The nasty thing I keep getting into is the "Script Error" message that karma spits out without any other relevant detail.

How can I make karma display the source of the error also ?

[image]

Comment: and no, the port is not the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little late, but as others may find this problem I thought I'd add some notes.

The `Script error` comes when the error is produced in a different domain than it's consumed. Browsers then remove the error details for security reasons. Typically this happens if:

- you load scripts/pages from different domains
- you run `eval` code. Note that this is what webpack often does in development scenarios

To mitigate this you can

- add relevant HTTP CORS headers
- skip running `eval` code - if you're running webpack, choose a devtool not containing "eval"
- load resources from the same domain

Hope it helps